# Node.js app not changing

Tags: node.js, git, pm2

I have a node app running on my VS using pm2, deployed via git.

All works fine, but when I make changes in my local version and then push it to the server the files are changed and updated to the new version, but the app still looks like the same of the initial push I made when I deployed it for the first time. Pm2 is set to watch for changes and in my local version all works fine, while on Vs not.

How is that possible?

UPDATE

Apparently it's just the .js file that isn't changed, html are fine.

Comment: What is VS? Visual Studio? Virtual Server?

Comment: @DrakaSAN Virtual Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently a rebase fixeded the problem:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
git push -u origin master
```